# What web hosting setup should I use for high traffic website?

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, hosting, high-traffic, google-compute-engine

I am fairly new to dealing with high traffic websites and I'm looking for a setup that will be able to scale well into the future.

My site currently uses one main script to pull data and store it into a database. The rest of the website is mostly presentation of this data from the database.

I have been looking at the possibility of using Amazon Web Services (EC2) or Google Compute Engine for running the main script. Then transferring that data to a more typical web hosting service. One thing I am not sure that I need to worry about is load balancing, I've seen that using NGINX for the load balancing can help improve the performance.

My goal is to have the site up 99.99% of the time and execute the script as fast as possible. It would be optimally nice to have a great support in case something goes wrong too.

Any ideas, comments, or suggestions are welcome. I'm am trying to learn how to handle this as I have a couple other websites that are currently growing and may need such a setup in the near future.

Thanks!

Comment: downvoted without a reason? At least give some kind of reason so I can improve my question and be better in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Google Compute Engine is still in its very early stages. For that reason alone, I would recommend using EC2. With EC2, you have all of the features you need. The ELB can seamlessly load balance between any amount of servers, which would help with the 99.99% uptime.

Using CloudFormation, you can define templates for scaling to run that script in a clustered environment.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! Just to be clear though, you are suggesting I run the entire site on AWS?

Answer (score 0):

Just find yourself a good host with a decent SLA, running a relational database within the cloud is asking for problems when you do get high database loads.

Don't be fooled, the cloud is a really nice solution for some problem.. but NOT ALL!
Same goes for NoSQL, and the combination of cloud and NoSQL.
Do your own research and don't be hoaxed by the marketing machines and the people not doing their homework.

Loadbalancing is nice but big change your database is the first bottleneck you run into.
Don't optimize thing before you need to!

If you are asking me, find yourself a decent dedicated (non-virtual) server with a decent SLA and backup plan.

Calculate howmuch 99.9% uptime actually is and realize that there is no problem in reaching that aslong as you have a decent SLA and proper backups.

You can always go from iron to the cloud,.. the other way around is a different story.